# Elastic search not searching for specific word

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have very strange problem in elastic search. I am searching using keyword 'samsung' and it shows perfect results but when I am searching using 'nokia' it shows nothing but the blank page. I have records for 'nokia' in DB. if I search using 'nokie', it shows results for nokia.

type mapping

```
'prod_name' => [
                            'type' => 'string'
                        ],
```

below is my elastic search query.

```
$params1 = [
            'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
            'type'  => $this->client->getType(),
            "from" => 0, "size" => 3000,
            'body'  => [
            "query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                             "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name","prod_model","keywords","prod_seo_keywords","prod_sku"],
                              "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                              "query" => $query
                          ]
                     ],

                  ]
               ]
            ]
            ],
       ];

$query1  = $client->search($params1);
```

Any help would be great!! Thnx.

Comment: Could you post the type mapping?

Comment: @Carlos type mapping is 'string'

Comment: have you tried best_fields type? The one that you are using only triggers if Nokia appears at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @Carlos I have one product names 'Nokia 6300 Silver On Orange PAYG Mobile Phone' so ideally it should work right?

Comment: It should but I never have used that certain type of query so I don't know the gotchas that it could have.